# Conditional statement in "each...do" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my erb file, I have the following code in the body tag:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>  
  <%= task.name %>
<% end %>
```

This is working, but I only want to display task.name if task.otherAttribute does not equal -1.

For some reason, I can't figure out how to do this! Any tips much would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>  
  <%= task.name if task.otherAttribute != 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Or:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>  
  <%= task.name unless task.otherAttribute == 1 %>
<% end %>
```

I will provide some more options for future reference:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <% if task.otherAttribute != 1 %>
    <%= task.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>  
  <%= task.otherAttribute == 1 ? '' : task.name %>
<% end %>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use `#select` and `#reject` for this idiom, since that's basically what you're doing.

```
<%= @tasks.reject{|t| t.other_attribute == -1}.each do |task| %>
  <%= task.name %>
<% end %>
```

These come from the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) module, which most things with an `#each` method include.

Comment: This was very helpful and worked just as I needed! Why do you use "t" instead of "task", though? Not clear on that bit.

Comment: @tonic, `task` would work fine too. It's actually bad practice on my part to use 1-letter variable names, though when the block only accepts one argument and has one line of logic anyway I tend to do it that way. Go with your instinct and use `task` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put conditionals into your ERB code.

```
<%= task.name if task.otherAttribute != 1 %>
```

You can also perform more complex tasks with a more verbose syntax. It's not necessary in your case, but you could also do more traditional if/else blocks like so:

```
<% if task.otherAttribute != 1 %>
  <%= task.name %>
<% end %>
```